# How to include app config file in WAR archive?

Tags: java, maven, jboss, war

I'm having trouble deploying a Java web app. It centers on our application config file (myapp.properties). In certain situations, having this file external to the WAR seems to work fine, but whenever I try to deploy it properly (Docker, proper JBoss deployment, etc.) the deployments inevitably fail due to being unable to find/read from myapp.properties.

I've seen a few references here and elsewhere to packaging these files *inside* the WAR archive, but I can't find any information on how to actually do that. So, my questions is:

What is the proper way to include an application config file in a WAR archive and/or deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It depends in how you want to access the file.

If you want to load it via classloader resources, you need it to be in the class-path, so the best location is inside `WEB-INF/classes`.

That's by the way, where resources in `src/main/resources` will end up [if you are using Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

You can also put it anywhere inside your WAR, for example, `WEB-INF/config` and access it via `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/....`. Beware but, that it's not inside the `WEB-INF` directory, you will have to explicitly forbid the access to the file in the `web.xml` deployement descriptor, otherwise it would be accessible to client requests.